# Pegar diferentes filas en otra hoja (Google sheet) bajo condiciones

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

**Mi objetivo**

En un prompt ingreso diferentes datos (*ejemplo: 1,2,3*), los cuales están alojados en la columna (D) de mi hoja "transporte" en diferentes filas, siendo datos únicos. Luego el código busca estos datos y obtiene los valores de toda la fila para cada dato, con 10 columnas de información. Para luego pegarlos en la hoja "envíos", fila por fila hacia abajo.

**PROBLEMA**

Las filas que se copian en la hoja "envíos" se sobrescriben, se pegan los valores para el dato (1) después el 2 encima y finalmente el 3, quedando este ultimo como visible en la hoja.

QUIERO QUE LAS FILAS SE PEGUEN UNA BAJO LA OTRA.

**MI CODIGO**

```
function rutaDinamica() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt(
    'Pedidos a transportar?',
    'Ingresa los pedidos:',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var datos = result.getResponseText().split(" ");
  var boton = result.getSelectedButton();
  var data = [];
  console.log(datos);

  datos.forEach(function (value) {
    const spreadsheetTR = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F1CEnVvU6Bv9zs38Kx0xo_RCQa1sF0cmmE6DCWa7IAw/edit#gid=0");
    var origen2 = spreadsheetTR.getSheetByName("Transporte");
    const depuracionTR = destino.getRange(2, 1, destino.getLastRow(), 10).clearContent();
    var columna = origen2.getRange("D:D")
    var textFinder = columna.createTextFinder(value);
    var ranges = textFinder.findAll();

    if (boton == ui.Button.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
        var celdas = origen2.setActiveSelection(ranges[i].getA1Notation());
        var filas = celdas.getRowIndex();
        var filasb = origen2.getRange(filas, 1, 1, 10).getDisplayValues();
        data.push(filasb);
      }
    }
    else if (boton == ui.Button.CANCEL) { }
    else if (boton == ui.Button.CLOSE) { }
  });
  const spreadsheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UaY9Ch7rpca1LWPLU1TivtssUaC8pILCu-wb_HHoV54/edit#gid=507705369");
  var destino = spreadsheet3.getSheetByName("Envios");
  Logger.log(data);

  destino.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```

---

**DATOS INGRESADOS AL PROMPT**

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w0Us7oOpoF0E9-K9Gzu5b10CEVrRIZYn/view?usp=sharing]
[image: DATOS PROMPT]

**RESULTADO DE CODIGO**

Si pueden ver, en la primera columna se pegan los datos (FY24), ya que ingrese 3 datos en el prompt con esa nomenclatura, pero las otras 9 columnas no se copian, como se ve en la imagen de abajo:

![Datos pegados][https://drive.google.com/file/d/144dnx4FcvmSpDboh7_6s1_G-x99P6jTM/view?usp=sharing]

Si hago log de la `data`, si recoge toda la información de las 10 columnas, dejo imagen en el enlace:

![LOG DATA] [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EgHD2fpnPgAbjQzFEIBtmKjKVBD2s4T7/view?usp=sharing]

**CÓDIGO ACTUAL**

```
function rutaDinamica() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt(
    'Pedidos a transportar?',
    'Ingresa los pedidos:',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var datos = result.getResponseText().split(" ");
  var boton = result.getSelectedButton();
  var data = [];

  var spreadsheetTR = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F1CEnVvU6Bv9zs38Kx0xo_RCQa1sF0cmmE6DCWa7IAw/edit#gid=0");
  var origen2 = spreadsheetTR.getSheetByName("Transporte");
  var spreadsheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UaY9Ch7rpca1LWPLU1TivtssUaC8pILCu-wb_HHoV54/edit#gid=507705369");
  var destino = spreadsheet3.getSheetByName("Envios");
  var depuracionTR = destino.getRange(2, 1, destino.getLastRow(), 10).clearContent();
  var columna = origen2.getRange("D:D")

  datos.forEach(function (value) {
    var textFinder = columna.createTextFinder(value);
    var ranges = textFinder.findAll();

    if (boton == ui.Button.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
        var celdas = origen2.setActiveSelection(ranges[i].getA1Notation());
        var filas = celdas.getRowIndex();
        var filasb = origen2.getRange(filas, 1, 1, 10).getValues();
        data.push(filasb);
      }
    }
    else if (boton == ui.Button.CANCEL) { }
    else if (boton == ui.Button.CLOSE) { }
  });
  destino.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: El script tiene varios problemas, por ejemplo, 1) la declaración de la variable `destino` se hace después de que esta variable es llamada. Esto debería impedir la ejecución del código.

Comment: 2) Considerando que las llamadas a los servicios de Google Apps Script son lentas, siempre que sea posible debe evitarse su uso un bucles, en lo particular no tiene sentido tener en un bucle declaraciones como `const spreadsheetTR = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F1CEnVvU6Bv9zs38Kx0xo_RCQa1sF0cmmE6DCWa7IAw/edit#gid=0");` ya no no hay ningún cambio en cada iteración. Esta línea bien puedes ponerla antes del bucle. Puedes hacer tu código mucho más eficiente poniendo los `if` que evalúan los botones fuera del bucle.

Comment: Si te fijas bien, la variable `destino` la llamo justo después de declararla, sin embargo, hice el arreglo que me mencionaste, y ahora, solo se pega la primera columna de información correctamente en la hoja "envíos", las otras 9 columnas quedan vacías.

Comment: Me he fijado muy bien :). La variable destino la llamas dos veces, una dentro del forEach y otra fuera. Quizás el código de la pregunta es diferente al que estás usando.

Comment: Para ser más específico, la siguiente línea causa un error porque `destino` es `null`: `const depuracionTR = destino.getRange(2, 1, destino.getLastRow(), 10).clearContent();`

Comment: Toda la razón, lo corregí arriba.

Aun así, no puedo solucionar que las filas se peguen en la hoja "envíos", solo copia la primera columna

Comment: Si ya has depurado el código con las observaciones previamente mencionadas, te sugiero reemplazar el código de la pregunta por el más reciente e incluir datos de muestra tanto de la hoja de cálculo como de los valores que estás indicando en el prompt.

Comment: Acabo de colocar el código actual y algunas pruebas mas.

Comment: Lo pegaste como respuesta. Las respuestas sólo deben usarse para responder la pregunta, no para reemplazar el código original ni para hacer aclaraciones. Por favor [edit] la pregunta. Por cierto, las imágenes deben de agregarse usando la herramienta para insertar imágenes, esto porque los recursos externos luego pueden dejar de estar disponibles y eso podría hacer que la pregunta no se entienda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya mencioné en mis comentarios a la pregunta, el código original tiene varios problemas. Uno que aún no había mencionado es que los datos que se están recolectando usando `Range.getDisplayValues()` en la variable `data` se pasan tal cual a dicha variable usando `Array.prototype.push`. Esto causa que `data` sea un `Array` de `Array` de `Array` de string (un "array 3D"), el problema es que que `Range.setValues(values)` espera que el parámetro sea un `Array` de `Array` (un "array 2D") de valores.

Una solución sencilla a lo anterior es modificar

```
var filasb = origen2.getRange(filas, 1, 1, 10).getValues();
data.push(filasb);
```

de la siguiente forma (agregar `[0]`)

```
var filasb = origen2.getRange(filas, 1, 1, 10).getValues()[0];
data.push(filasb);
```

Problemas mencionados en los comentarios

1. El código en la versión original de la pregunta declara la variable `destino` casi al final del de la función pero esta es llamada antes por lo que causaría un TypeError pues el `undefined` no tiene el método `getRange`.
2. El declarar variables dentro de un bucle usando métodos de Google Apps Script que devuelven lo mismo en cada iteración es potencialmente ineficiente. Digo potencialmente porque Google Apps Script internamente tiene algoritmos para eficientar pero sólo haciendo pruebas se podría saber en cada caso si están siendo efectivos. Lo mejor es no depender de dichos algoritmos. Una solución sencilla de esto es mover esos métodos fuera del bucle.
3. El tener los `if` que evalúan la respuesta del prompt dentro del bucle también ineficiente aunque el impacto podría ser relativamente menor. Por "buenas prácticas" Lo mejor es poner estos `if` fuera del bucle.

Otros problemas

La siguiente línea es altamente ineficiente:

`var celdas = origen2.setActiveSelection(ranges[i].getA1Notation());`

Lo anterior porque, dentro de un bucle, usa dos métodos de Apps Script siendo uno de ellos uno que afecta la interfaz de usuario.

una solución simple es reemplazarla por:

`var celdas = ranges[i];`

Comment: Ruben, muchas gracias, esas 2 correcciones me soluciono el problema. Muchas gracias.